# Homebrew installed git not working

Tags: macos, homebrew, git

I installed git with Homebrew and `/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.31.1/bin` is supposed to be the directory where the `git` executable is installed. BUT none of the commands are working:

```
rgdgr8$ /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.31.1/bin/git --version
rgdgr8$ /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.31.1/bin/git
rgdgr8$
```

I just don't know why.

Comment: Please copy text from terminal as text so all can read it

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Could you add the output of `file /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.31.1/bin/git`, `otool -L /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.31.1/bin/git`and `ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.31.1/bin/git`?

Comment: @RitobrotoGanguly Please make your solution an answer don't do it as an edit to the question

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! I had another git folder in /usr/local/ which had symlinks in /usr/local/bin. So I had to move that git folder elsewhere and then installed and reinstalled git with homebrew.